# Facebook rating API not returning a reviewer name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Facebook rating app not showing reviewer name and only showing my name if I had reviewed before not any other name please help me out. Attach is the image of Facebook API response kindly check it.

[image: rating API response kindly check it]

Comment: probably not possible anymore because of data privacy, or maybe you need to get your app reviewed first.